# PHP - create strict typed Map dynamically (multidimensional)?

Tags: php, data-structures, strict

I need to be able to create strict typed maps dynamically. Like this:

```
$map = new Map( 'string,array<string,int>', [
  'foo' => [
    'bar' => 1
  ]
];
```

I have seen a lot of solutions for separate cases. All guides are teaching to create a class for each map, like `Users_Map` (to keep users there), `Products_Map` (to keep products there),  `Comments_Map` (to keep comments there), etc.

But I don't want to have 3 classes (dozens in fact - for a big project) for each type of the map. I want to create a single class `Map` and then use it like this:

```
$users = new Map( 'User', {users data goes here} );

$products = new Map( 'int,Product', {products data goes here} );

$comments = new Map( 'User,array<Comment>', {comments data goes here} );
```

I would appreciate if somebody can advice me any existing repos. Otherwise I'll probably implement this on my own and will put here a link to my solution as an answer.

Comment: PHP doesn't support strict typing very well, why do you need that?

Comment: @Barmar, just want to make my code more consistent. I often get bugs due to arrays are not strict typed. Just want to save development time by avoiding the bugs.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called generics. PHP doesn't support this, although there has been [an RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generics) calling for support for a few years.

If you really want to enforce strict typing on a custom map, you'd have to build it yourself. You could, for example, do something like this:

```
class Map {
    private string $keyType;
    private string $valueType;
    
    private array $items;
    
    public function __construct(string $keyType, string $valueType) {
        $this->keyType = $keyType;
        $this->valueType = $valueType;
    }
    
    public function set($key, $value) {
        if (gettype($key) !== $this->keyType && !($key instanceof $this->keyType)) {
            throw new TypeError("Key must be of type " . $this->keyType);
        }
        
        if (gettype($value) !== $this->valueType && !($value instanceof $this->valueType)) {
            throw new TypeError("Value must be of type " . $this->valueType);
        }
        
        $this->items[$key] = $value;
    }
    
    public function get($key) {
        if (gettype($key) !== $this->keyType) {
            throw new TypeError("Key must be of type " . $this->keyType);
        }
        
        return $this->items[$key] ?? null;
    }
    
    public function all() {
        return $this->items;
    }
}
```

(of course, this particular implementation uses a regular `array` internally, so `keyType` is limited to types that are valid array keys. If you want to support other object types, some more interesting logic might be required)

The combination of `gettype` and `instanceof` will ensure this works for both simple and complex types. For example:

```
$map = new Map("string", "array");
$map->set("name", ["Boris", "Johnson"]);
print_r($map->all());

/*
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Boris
            [1] => Johnson
        )
)
*/

$map->set("job", "Prime Minister");
// Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Value must be of type array
```

Or with a class as value type:

```
class User {
    public string $firstName;
    public string $lastName;
}

$user = new User();
$user->firstName = "Boris";
$user->lastName = "Johnson";

$map = new Map("string", User::class);
$map->set("pm", $user);
print_r($map->all());

/*
Array
(
    [pm] => User Object
        (
            [firstName] => Boris
            [lastName] => Johnson
        )

)
*/
```

If you also want to support nested generics, like in your example `array<string,int>`, that becomes more complicated. In that case, as soon as someone passes an array as a value, you'd have to manually check all items in the array to ensure all array keys are strings and all array values are integers. It's possible, but for larger arrays it will be a significant performance hit.

Although you could use a nested `Map` like this one if you extend it to enforce the types:

```
class StringIntMap extends Map {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct("string", "integer");
    }
}

$map = new Map("string", StringIntMap::class);
```